# Can't unlock folders with "Any Folder Password Lock" software

Tags: windows, security, lock, folder-lock

[image: Software screenshot]
I'm using a software called Any Folder Password Lock and it's not unlocking my folder anymore..

I tried to uninstall it but the folder is still locked and I'm pretty sure what password I use to lock the folder, but it's still giving me wrong password ..

Is there any solution to unlock the folder with REGEDIT or some tools ?

Comment: That particular tool does not use the Windows registry. The only tool that can decrypt your folder is that tool.  Which is precisely the reason you should be using EFS built-into Windows instead of a third-party application to encrypt the contents of a folder

Comment: The developer has support contact information here: https://www.any-password-recovery.com/support.html

Comment: I would advise not to use any third-party software to lock your files. In case of a bug, you lose your files.

Comment: @harrymc, that said, VeraCrypt is useful for protecting sensitive data on portable media, *among various platforms*, but, as you state, that should not be the *only* copy -- an error in a single bit can make a copy unreadable.

Comment: For the purposes of my comment, I do not necessarily consider VeraCrypt a third-party tool, but it also isn't an EFS tool but a tool to accomplish Full Disk Encryption or encrypted containers.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the very nature of this tool, we cannot answer your question here except to refer to you the developer.

If a file or folder encryption tool was able to be circumvented by simple registry manipulation, it would be pointless and rightly laughed at and discarded.

While I cannot speak to the efficacy or quality of this tool, the fact the folder remains "locked" and does not offer a way of unlocking outside this tool means that, at this at least, it is functioning properly.

As Ramhound noted: If you're using Windows, you will have better options as well as valid but still secure methods of access after credential issues using Windows' own built in tools.

Comment: I tried to contact them but support email doesn't exist!.. I'm stuck now and maybe I will have to do data recovery even though the data is still there.. 
So my theory so far is that the company is scamming people by locking your folder with the password you never chose, and forcing users to purchase the software to get the support needed ..

Comment: The encrypted folder extension is .afpl if that helps anyone